# Send Javascript to page through vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to send a javascript to the page for a loader after a button click.

The button is also in a gridview so I'm not sure how to do OnClientClick but I thought I could do it from the vb.net back end so I tried doing this:

```
    If (e.CommandName = "View") Then
        Dim row2 As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Button).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        If (Not (row2) Is Nothing) Then

            Dim DateSaved As String = row2.Cells(0).Text


            Dim javaScript As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

            javaScript.Append("<script type=""text/javascript"">" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("function ShowProgress() {" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("window.onload = function()" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("setTimeout(function () {" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("var modal = $('<div />');" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("modal.addClass(""modal"");" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("$('body').append(modal);" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("var loading = $("".loading"");" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("loading.show();" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("loading.css({ top: top, left: left });" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("}, 200);" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("}" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("$('form').live(""submit"", function () {" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("ShowProgress();" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("});" + Constants.vbLf)
            javaScript.Append("</script>" + Constants.vbLf)
            Me.RegisterStartupScript("LoadScript", javaScript.ToString())
```

Comment: Can you describe what this code does wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- I don't see how you hide your loader once the postback is finished ?
- Since you are using jQuery, why use `window.onload` instead of jQuery's document.ready() ?
- Writing javascript in a string is hideous, it's unreadable and you don't benefict from syntax highlight, write in a .js file and use [RegisterClientScriptInclude](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/kx145dw2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Anyway you should use ASP.NET built-in control to do this [UpdateProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx):

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
  <ProgressTemplate>
     Processing...
  </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Just make sure your gridview is wrapped around an UpdatePanel and the UpdateProgress will display it's template every time a postback occurs.

Comment: But there are other buttons in the gridview that I do not want loading the progress template that are inside the gridview